# Android Studio Can't Fetch Library

Tags: android, gradle, retrofit, okio

I have recently started getting this issue with Android Studio and it has been driving me up the wall. I keep getting the error "Failed to resolve: com.squareup.okio:okio:1.8.0". These are the dependencies I have:

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

    compile files('libs/okio-1.8.0.jar')

    compile files('libs/retrofit-2.1.0 (1).jar')
   }
```

As you can see, I have the retrofit and gson libraries simply compile (I'm assuming this downloads them from the internet), I tried doing the same with Okio however it didn't resolve, so I have speicifcally downloaded the 1.8.0 Okio JAR however it still fails to resolve. Why could this be? Any answer would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: have you tried compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.9.0' ?

Comment: try clean and rebuild project

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/16628496/1157879

Comment: @JemilRiahi yes I have, I am still given the error for 1.8.0 for some reason

Comment: @UmarAta I have tried that, no difference

Answer (score 0):

Don't put dependencies as a `Gradle` dependency:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
```

And as a .jar file in `src/libs`:

```
compile files('libs/retrofit-2.1.0 (1).jar')
```

**at one time**. Choose only one method. I advise you to choose `Gradle` dependencies, because they are automatically fetched.

In you case, the `dependencies` section should look like:

```
dependencies {
    compile `com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7`
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

}